# Access a record through a Restlet, Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to do something fairly simple that is somehow causing me some problems.
I'm trying to access a Record on Netsuite through a Restlet.

here is my code:

```
/**
@NApiVersion 2.x
@NModuleSc​o​p​e Public
@NScriptType Restlet
*/ 
define(['N/record'], function(record) {
  function getRecord() {

    var recordType = 'salesorder'; // I've also tried record.TYPE.SALES_ORDER
    var recordID = 'CONF39932'; //A hardcoded sales_order Id just to try to get something back

    var loadedRecord = record.load({
      type: recordType,
      id: recordID
    });

    return { msg: loadedRecord };
  }

  return {
    get: getRecord
  };
});
```

I get back a pretty cryptic error:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":null,"stack":["loadRecord_impl(N/recordImpl)","getRecord(/SuiteScripts/customTest/getRecord.js:12)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","details":null,"userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["loadRecord_impl(N/recordImpl)","getRecord(/SuiteScripts/customTest/getRecord.js:12)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"73f69a57-afa8-4c3e-854c-493add4cf222-2d323031382e31322e3031","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}"
```

Anybody has any tips?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id should be the Internal ID of the record, not the record's name.

also, type is record.Type.SALES_ORDER - it's case sensitive.

Comment: I suppose the ENUM record.Type.SALES_ORDER may end up actually being 'salesorder', but you should use the ENUM. It's better form.